# Return type depending on optional generic type Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, option-type

I made the following function to generate an object (map) [key] : value from an array.
I want to make the `value` method optional, and in this case just return the item as it is.
Here is my code :

```
   export default class ArrayUtils {
      /** Return a map from array like { [key]: value } */
      static toMap = <T, T2 = void, V = T2 extends void ? T : T2>(
        array: T[],
        key: (item: T) => string | number,
        value: (item: T) => V = (item: T) => item,
      ): { [key: string | number]: V } => Object.fromEntries(array.map((item) => [key(item), value(item)]));
    }
```

But I get the following error in the IDE:

> Type '(item: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(item: T) => V'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'V'.
> 'V' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'

How can I achieve what I want ? I already tried to overload the function unsuccesfully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally ended up with the following code:

```
// type Key = string | number;
  /** Return a map from array like { [key]: value } */
  static toMap<T, V>(array: T[], key: (item: T) => Key, value: (item: T) => V): { [key in Key]: V };
  static toMap<T>(array: T[], key: (item: T) => Key): { [key in Key]: T };
  static toMap<T, V = void>(array: T[], key: (item: T) => Key, value?: (item: T) => V): { [key in Key]: V | T } {
    return Object.fromEntries(array.map((item) => [key(item), value ? value(item) : item]));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be to tell the compiler that you know what you are doing by force-casting your T type to V using this syntax for the default value method: `(item: T) => item as unknown as V`. I guess the correct solution would be to tell that your value method can return both V and T types like so: `value: (item: T) => T | V`

Note that this error means that this conversion is not safe, as `'V' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'`.

Overall, I don't get why you use 4 generic types for this method, as you want to translate a `T` item to a `K` and `V`, knowing that the key will be of type `string | number`.

Edited version:

```
static toMap<T, V>(
    array: T[],
    key: (item: T) => string | number,
    value: (item: T) => T | V = (item: T) => item,
): { [key: string | number]: V } {
  return Object.fromEntries(array.map((item) => [key(item), value(item)]));
}
```

Comment: You are right, I removed `K extends string | number` because I know it already. I do not want my function to be `value: (item: T) => T | V` because when I call it, I already know which type I want to return. Having the option to be `T | V` make some other compilation errors in my project code

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark `value` as an optional parameter using the `?` sign and change `value`'s return type from `T` to `V | T`.
2. To match the updated return type(`V | T`), you need to call `value(item)` only if `value` is provided, otherwise return `item`

```
export default class ArrayUtils {
  /** Return a map from array like { [key]: value } */
  static toMap = <T, K extends string | number, T2 = void, V = T2 extends void ? T : T2>(
    array: T[],
    key: (item: T) => K,
    value?: (item: T) => V | T,
  ): { [key: string | number]: V | T } => Object.fromEntries(array.map((item) => [key(item), value ? value(item) : item]));
}
```

Comment: Hi your answer is interesting ! However I do not want my function to be value: (item: T) => T | V because when I call it, I already know which type I want to return. Having the option to be T | V make some other compilation errors in my project code